# PHP function code errors

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below is the code from one of my php files. It seems to have compilation errors. I am new to php.

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong below in php function code:

```
function eshop_extras_checkout($echo){


    $echo .= '<script>

    $(".formGroup").hide();
$('#chooseForm input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
    }
    else {
        $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
    }   
});
​   
    </script>';

    $echo .= '<fieldset class="eshop eshop_extra">' . "\n";


     $echo .= ' <form id="chooseForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form1"> Form1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form2"> Form2<br>
</form>

<form id="form1" class="formGroup">
    <h2>FORM 1</h2>
    <label>Name</label><input type="text"> <br>
    <label>Address</label><input type="text">
</form>

<form id="form2" class="formGroup">
    <h2>FORM 2</h2>
    <label>Username</label><input type="text"> <br>
</form>';


    $echo .= '<legend>Articles Order Form</legend>' . "\n";



    return $echo;


}
```

**This is the error in my browser:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/harris12/public_html/somedomain.com/wp-content/plugins/eshop-extras/eshop-extras.php on line 43

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting and tell us what you see.

Comment: quotes inside quotes. ouch. this looks like a job for HEREDOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 <?php
function eshop_extras_checkout($echo){


    $echo .= '<script>

    $(".formGroup").hide();
    $("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
        }
    });
    ​
</script>';

    $echo .= '<fieldset class="eshop eshop_extra">' . "\n";


    $echo .= ' <form id="chooseForm">
        <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form1"> Form1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form2"> Form2<br>
    </form>

    <form id="form1" class="formGroup">
        <h2>FORM 1</h2>
        <label>Name</label><input type="text"> <br>
        <label>Address</label><input type="text">
    </form>

    <form id="form2" class="formGroup">
        <h2>FORM 2</h2>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text"> <br>
    </form>';


    $echo .= '<legend>Articles Order Form</legend>' . "\n";



    return $echo;
}
    ?>
```

You should have either escaped the apostrophes or used double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
$('#chooseForm input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
```

you have the ' character in your code and thus end the echo-command. Thats why its interpreted and php code which obviously results in an error. Try escaping it with \'

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the ' (apostrophes)

```
$('#chooseForm input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
```

as it's breaking out your first echo statement

Answer (score 1):

The first string you're concatenating to `$echo` has single quotes inside of single quotes.

```
if($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Try changing them to double quotes.

Is there a reason why you have to build up this string by concatenation?  It doesn't actually appear that you're executing anything in PHP at all.  You should do this the other way around and leave all of this mark-up as-is, but intersperse any actual PHP code with `<?  ... ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a re-write using HEREDOC:

```
function eshop_extras_checkout($output){
  $output .= <<<ESHOP_SCRIPT
<script>
   $(".formGroup").hide();
  $('#chooseForm input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
  }
  else {
     $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
  }   
  });
</script>
<fieldset class="eshop eshop_extra">
 <form id="chooseForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form1" /> Form1<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form2" /> Form2<br />
 </form>
 <form id="form1" class="formGroup">
  <h2>FORM 1</h2>
  <label>Name</label><input type="text" /> <br>
  <label>Address</label><input type="text" />
 </form>
 <form id="form2" class="formGroup">
  <h2>FORM 2</h2>
  <label>Username</label><input type="text" /> <br>
 </form>
 <legend>Articles Order Form</legend>
 ESHOP_SCRIPT;
 return $output;
}
```